# Authenticate AWS Lambda in Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

Issue: I want to authenticate the response from lambda to Django

Summary: My Django app invokes an AWS Lambda with some url, lambda does the processing and a couple of seconds later should return the result to Django. Now, how do I ensure that the response from lambda is valid, and it's not someone trying to call my django endpoint?

Setup:

Django running on an EC2 machine behind nginx + uwsgi

Lambda called from Django using

```
boto3.client('lambda').invoke(
    FunctionName="my-lambda-name",
    InvocationType='Event',
    Payload=json.dumps(payload)
))
```

Lambda code:

```
def handler(event, context):
    data = event['data']
    result = get_my_result(data)
    requests.post('https://www.example.com/foo/bar', data=json.dumps(result))
```

I was considering Django REST framework, but it's not like I have a specific user calling the lambda, so I think it doesn't quite suite the purpose.

I have never done this kind of 3rd party service authentication in Django, not sure what the most elegant (+secure and efficient) approach would be.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're invoking the Lambda function synchronously. Have you considered simply returning the JSON results directly in the payload of the Lambda response, rather than POSTing them back asynchronously?

Comment: Actually it was being invoked asynchronously (edited now), but it could be a good idea to wait for response, given that this is not running on my main thread.

Comment: If it needs to be async, then perhaps you could simply send a random token with the request to Lambda that the Lambda would send back in the POSTed response as authentication. All interaction with Lambda is encrypted so it would be safe for your Django app to create a token and transmit it with the request. There are also more sophisticated options (like real authentication of the POST, perhaps using credentials vended by Parameter Store).

Comment: Ok, thanks for suggestions, will look into them