# How do I authenticate a Lambda function to access a Django endpoint?

Tags: django, aws-lambda, django-authentication

Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49150673/authenticate-aws-lambda-in-django) question appears to be identical, but actual problem asked is unanswered and the OP ends up changing his entire approach.

Suppose I have some lambda-based application that I want to let access my Django application. How do I authenticate it?

I could just give the lambda function a username/password, but that's far from ideal in a long term security context.

Is there a way to directly authenticate a lambda function in django? Alternatively, are there better security practices that could be employed (i.e. secret rotation) so that this can be done?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean with "endpoint"? Did you build a REST/GraphQL API with something like Django REST Framework? In this case those frameworks offer multiple ways of authenticating users. If you use AWS API Gateway you could use Cognito or a custom authorizer you write to authenticate requests to your Django API. But I am afraid without more information about your project it is hard to help you.

Comment: @Jens I am using regular Django (not the REST framework) and currently my only authentication backend so far is SAML. The app is served directly as a pod behind a loadbalancer on ECS and does not use API gateway. 

I know there are multiple authentication backends I can configure with Django, but I don't know if there's one specifically for connecting to AWS resources (via IAM, metadata, etc.). Otherwise it seems like I would need to hardcode some long-term credential on the lambda itself.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information: What you have and want you want to do etc.

Comment: @Godot-Dev how did you solve this? I have the exact same problem